# Turin Turambar and Dagor Dagorath

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

I have a question about Turin's role in the Dagor Dagorath:

How is Turin going to return to Middle Earth for the final day of doom?

Comment: One question per question.

Comment: The answer is Eru, Eru, and yes, everyone will be.

Comment: I don't think you understand why this question was closed. Your question was closed because it was asking three questions, but [we want to keep one "question" post limited to a single question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/when-are-we-okay-with-multiple-questions-in-one). Although your questions are linked by a common theme, they are all very distinct questions, and as such should have separate posts

Comment: Each of these questions is good, but each one needs to be asked separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is Prophecy. We don't know that it is going to happen, it is just "said" that is what happens.

If it does happen it will be done at the will of Eru, who hasn't revealed to anyone, even to the Valar what happens to men when they die.